# Adding Quotations and Brackets to format of cell conditionally

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have three columns:

```
Word    | Formatted Word | Type
Chicken |................| Noun
Running |................| Verb
```

If the word in `A2` is a Noun, I would like `B2`, the formatted word, to look like this: `"Chicken"`.  If `A2` is a Verb, then I would want the word to look like this: `[Chicken]`. Is there a way to do this? I can't seem to get it to do it correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried a lot of things.  I was having a hard time because of the quotations and brackets having other purposes.  I figured it out on my own by using CHAR(34) for quotations.   But, it looks like the options below also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually wanted the quotes then

```
=IF(C12="Noun",""""&A12&"""",IF(C12="Verb","["&A12&"]",""))
```

would be the formula you want in B.

Comment: Why are there 4 quotes on either side of the &A2&?   I imagine one of those is escaping the inner quote, but what about the other two?

Comment: Two quotes inside a string is a quote `"Hello ""you"" there."` would display in the cell as `Hello "you" there.` Four quotes is just two quotes inside of two other quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Using a nested [`IF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) statement, you can check if `C2` is `Noun` or `Verb`. Then tell is what to do in each case.

```
=IF(C2="Noun", A2, IF(C2="Verb", "[" & A2 & "]", " "))
```

The first if checks `C2` for the word `Noun`. If it is present, it returns the `A2` to the cell. If is is not `Noun`, it looks to see if the word is `Verb`. If it is, it returns the word from `A2` with brackets. If it is neither `Noun` or `Verb` it returns nothing.

You can nest additional if statements for other conditions.

Comment: for nouns it's requested to be formatted like `"word"`, your solution miss `"`

Answer (score 0):

Just put in a conditional that looks at the type column to see what is given there.

`=if(c2="Noun",A2, "[" & A2 &"]" )`
If the first argument  (`C2="Noun"`) resolves as true, then it will return the second argument (`A2`).  Otherwise it will return the result of concatenating A2 with the two brackets.

Note that this solution will put A2 in brackets if C2 is ANYTHING other than "Noun."

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach with `SUBSTITUTE` instead of concatenation, it'll give you a more readable formula when you expand your formula to more type of words:
`=SUBSTITUTE(IF(C2="Noun","""x""",IF(C2="Verb","[x]","")),"x",A2)`

Instead of nested if you can even make it more clear by using support range (one column for word type and another one for format) and `VLOOKUP`

Comment: I didn't know about substitute.  That is pretty interesting.  Thank you.